# Scheduling Jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scheduled-tasks

I would like to know how I can schedule jobs that are recurring over and over again like loading data from an api service or sending emails. I found `resque` and `resque-scheduler` but it uses Redis as backend what is an overkill dependency for fix-timed jobs.

Is there a way to schedule ruby code blocks in rails environment for a fixed time without the external dependencies?

Answer (score 3):

i guess you are looking for something like whenever: https://github.com/javan/whenever

it uses crontab to schedule your work.

Comment: could you tell me when the jobs are created, if they are persistent (rails instance offline) and if the rails environment will be loaded every single time? [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/whenever-gem/5VHhSJ4EXpU)'s a thread i created for the questions

Answer (score 1):

You can also checkout Rufus scheduler https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler which also uses crontab to schedule, and it has some extra features which you may like it as well!

Comment: Sorry, rufus-scheduler uses the same domain language as cron[tab], but it doesn't use the cron daemon of the underlying system, it's independent.

Answer (score 0):

As phoet recommend you, whenever is the gem you need. I will also recommend you sidekiq instead of resque. Sidekiq is newer and has better performance. Theres a Railscast about sidekiq, you should check it out.

Comment: yes, whatever is not bad but rufus-scheduler looks better to me because the documentation is more detailed.